# GoogleScraper Installation error - setuptools must be installed

Tags: python, web-scraping, pip, virtualenv

I have virtualenv-13.1.2 set up with python 3.4 (global python is python-2.7) in ubuntu 14.04. When I try to install GoogleScraper using coammand`pip install GoogleScraper` it gives an error

> setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution

If I do `pip install setuptools`

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./env/lib/python3.4/site-packages

If I do `pip install setuptools --upgrade`

> Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in ./env/lib/python3.4/site-packages

How can I successfully install GoogleScraper?

Comment: Hi, did you solve your issue ? I'm running into the same errors.

Comment: nope I havnt solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing python3-dev tools. I did `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the `python3.4` package in Ubuntu 14.04 I get the same error.

A quick solution is to delete and re-create the virtualenv.